# Vue 3 defineEmits breaks defineProps types

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and TS 4.4. I've got a component that defines its prop types with `defineProps`. When I add a call to `defineEmits`, VS Code starts telling me my `props` variable doesn't exist in the component template. Here's the source code:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, defineEmits, VueElement, defineComponent } from "vue";

const emit = defineEmits<{
  "update:checked": boolean;
}>();

const props = defineProps<{
  label?: VueElement | string;
  checked?: boolean;
}>();
</script>

<template>
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :checked="props.checked"
      @change="(event) => emit('update:checked', (event.target as any)?.checked)"
    />
    {{ props.label }}
  </label>
</template>
```

And a couple of screenshots to better show what I'm seeing in VS Code. This is after adding `defineEmits`:

[image: VS Code TS error]

And this is without `defineEmits`:

[image: VS Code without TS error]

What is the correct way to define types for both props and emits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`defineEmits<T>()` generic argument](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features) is essentially a TypeScript interface that defines only *functions*, which receive a specific event name and optional arguments:

```js
interface Emits {
  (e: __EVENT1_NAME__ [, arg1: __ARG1_TYPE__ [, arg2: __ARG2_TYPE__]]...): void
  (e: __EVENT2_NAME__ [, arg1: __ARG1_TYPE__ [, arg2: __ARG2_TYPE__]]...): void
}
```

*Examples:*

```js
// as inline type
const emits = defineEmits<{
  (eventName: 'hover', hovering: boolean): void
  (eventName: 'changed', newValue: number, id: string): void
}>()
```

```js
// as interface
interface Emits {
  (eventName: 'hover', hovering: boolean): void
  (eventName: 'changed', newValue: number, id: string): void
}
const emits = defineEmits<Emits>()
```

```js
// as type alias
type Emits = {
  (eventName: 'hover', hovering: boolean): void
  (eventName: 'changed', newValue: number, id: string): void
}
const emits = defineEmits<Emits>()
```

For your `update:checked` event, the code should look similar to the following:

```js
// as inline type
const emits = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:checked', checked: boolean): void
}>()
```

```js
// as interface
interface Emits {
  (e: 'update:checked', checked: boolean): void
}
const emits = defineEmits<Emits>()
```

```js
// as type alias
type Emits = {
  (e: 'update:checked', checked: boolean): void
}
const emits = defineEmits<Emits>()
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to achieve this with the Options API?

Comment: @gardarh Yes, the [`emits` option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#emits).

Comment: Thanks! Just for anyone else encountering problems with the emits option: It looks like Volar support is a little flaky, occasionally the types are not propagated to the parent. Also, the emits option requires you to write a validation function  to declare types which feels a little verbose. Further discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192220/typing-vue-3-emits-with-options-api