# Typing vue 3 emits with Options API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Is there a way to type an emits in vue 3 Options API similarly to Composition API?
According to Composition way ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits)):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
// type-based
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'change', id: number): void
  (e: 'update', value: string): void
}>()
</script>
```

But for Options API we have only payload validation ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-component-emits)):

```
emits: {
    addBook(payload: { bookName: string }) {
      // perform runtime validation
      return payload.bookName.length > 0
    }
  }
```

Therefore, if we don't need validation, eslint will consider parameters as unused:

```
emits: {
    change: (id: number) => true // 'id' is defined but never used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add an ignore-comment to silence the warning:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
change: (id: number) => true
```

Or implement a trivial validation on `id`:

```js
change: (id: number) => typeof id === 'number'
```

Comment: I would like to find a cleaner way. At least, it does work as is.

Comment: There's unfortunately no other way to type the emit in the Options API. You'd just have to deal with eslint.